# Terraform - How to modify map keys?

Tags: terraform, interpolation, amazon-ecs

In Terraform 0.12.xx, is it possible to modify the keys in the map instead of their respective values? Let us assume that we have the following in the module definition:

```
locals {
    task_logging = [
    for k, v in var.task_logging_options : {
      name = trimprefix(k,"TASK_LOGGING_")
      value = v
    }
  ]
}
```

However, `trimprefix` here only applies on value.

Then down below I am creating a task definition for ECS service:

```
{...}
"logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
        "secretOptions": [],
        "options": ${jsonencode(local.task_logging_options)}
    },
{...}
```

And finally, in the module instantiation, I am passing `task_logging_options` as follows:

```
task_logging_options = {
    TASK_LOGGING_Name = "es"
    TASK_LOGGING_Host = "some.host"
  }
```

Where local function should strip the prefix `TASK_LOGGING_` to build a JSON object for Fluentbit configuration.

End result should be an object, similar to snippet from terraform plan:

```
~ logConfiguration = {
                        logDriver     = "awsfirelens"
                      ~ options       = {
                          - Buffer_Size       = "False" -> null
                          - HTTP_Passwd       = "READACTED" -> null
                          - HTTP_User         = "READACTED" -> null
                          - Host              = "READACTEDd" -> null
                          - Index             = "READACTED" -> null
                          - Name              = "es" -> null
                          - Port              = "READACTED" -> null
                          + TASK_LOGGING_Host = "some.host"
                          + TASK_LOGGING_Name = "es"
                          - Tls               = "On" -> null
                          - Trace_Output      = "On" -> null
                        }
                        secretOptions = []
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully understand what do you want to achieve, but you can use `trimprefix(k,"TASK_LOGGING_")` as key as well.

For example:

```
locals { 
  task_logging2 = [
    for k, v in var.task_logging_options : {
        trimprefix(k,"TASK_LOGGING_") = v
      }
    ]  
}
```

will result in `local.task_logging2` being:

```
[
  {
    "Host" = "some.host"
  },
  {
    "Name" = "es"
  },
]
```

#### Update

If object is required, the following could be used:

```
locals {
  
  task_logging2 = {
    for k, v in var.task_logging_options : 
        trimprefix(k,"TASK_LOGGING_") => v
      }   
}
```

which results in `local.task_logging2` being:

```
{
  "Host" = "some.host"
  "Name" = "es"
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. Maybe I forgot to mention, that the result should be an object. I will edit my question.

Comment: @AlanKis I updated the answer, which gives object now.